# yo angular EACCESS error when creating package.json

Tags: angularjs, yo

After having done the command line "yo angular" and following the difference steps, I got this error :

[Screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bagC7.png)

I tried to run it as "sudo yo angular" but it did not fix the issue.

Any ideas of a solution ?
Thank you

Comment: try by opening admin `command prompt` for windows and `sudo su` for ubuntu

Comment: It's clearly mentioned in last line

Comment: With your indications :here is what I got :
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.json'
You don't have access to this file.

    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:641:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:509:33)
    at Object.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
    at Object.Configstore.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:81:13)

Comment: give it a try, it won't be dangerous with yo angular

Comment: I hope you tried like this `sudo su` then after entering password `yo angular`

Comment: I tried. :) but:
I got an other error, see the previous comment I did

Comment: Here is the beginning of the error. You can see that I am running it as sudo su:

sh-3.2# yo angular
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.json'
You don't have access to this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some of these

```
npm cache clean
```

and

```
bower cache clean
```

Or

```
sudo chown username /var/root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.json
```

or

```
sudo chown /var/root/.config/configstore/insight-yo.json
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: npm + bower cache clean helped me Sacha. Thank you for you help.